# How can I fit this view in all screen size; Percentage based or grid based

Tags: css, grid, screen, fullscreen, screen-resolution

[image]

I have a top strip and what approach i have to use?

Table or grid or percentage.
and write media query for font optimization ?
Any percentage based css framework ?

Irrespective of screen size and resolution I need to show it in a screen with out scroll.

Thanks for support.

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a structure like this:

```css
   
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

ul:after{
    clear:both;
}

ul li{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 18%;
    display:inline-block;
}
ul li div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
   <ul>

   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>
   <li><div>Your Content</div></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; how to set height? If content exceed it will create scroll. I think I need to write media query and optimize font accordingly. Is this correct @saurav

Comment: Yes, you have to use media query for different screen resolution as per your need.

Comment: If it is really helpful for you. Then, please accept my answer.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks. If it is a media query approach, It is equal to bootstrap right? I am think of percentage approach will it work

Comment: Ya, you can give percentage on different media screens according to your need. I mean to say tick my answer to green.